# Moving with overwriting smaller files

Tags: linux, bash, file

Any clue how can I move files and overwrite those in target directory only when target files are smaller?

I was looking for some bash solution but wasn't able to find any with support for standard wildcards.

Pseudocode would look like:

```
WHEN mv -i is triggering prompt AND input_file_size > target_file_size:
    mv input_file target_file
```

Comment: Not sure if you can easily check by file size, but mv has the `-u` switch for update, which will compare file dates. Would that work for you?

Comment: I know about `-u` switch but I need size comparing in this case. Eg. for static directories and without wildcards it would be easy to `touch` bigger files and then use `-u` but it's also complicating things.

Comment: Is the data that already exists in a smaller target file identical with the start of the bigger input file?

Comment: In most cases no it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't allow you to get file size in-process.
You can do something like

```
sz0=$(stat -c%s input_file)
sz1=$(stat -c%s target_file)
if ((sz1 < sz0)); then mv input_file target_file; fi
```

but don't expect hyperspeed if you want to run this in a loop.

Comment: This gonna be slow from what I can see. I'm not so good with bash scripting yet but idea with catching `-i` prompt is not easy to script?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "catching `-i`"

Comment: Lets say I have 3 files in INPUT directory and 1 duplicated (by name) but smaller file in TARGET dir. Your way is checking size for all files which is pointless. Catching `mv -i` - prompt before overwrite would make it happen only when there're same files in both directories so for one file in INPUT and one file (with same name) in TARGET dir.